# Suspend/Resume a process the easy way?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

Is there an easier way to suspend/resume a process without having to fire up resource monitor?

[image: screenshot]

Perhaps a command-line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[PsSuspend](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897540.aspx) from Sysinternals sounds like a good option for this.

Answer (score 5):

If you use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) as a Task Manager replacement (like I do), then you get the functionality right in your task manager:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/hi-in/sysinternals/bb896653%28en-us%29.aspx) and [process freezer](http://download.cnet.com/Free-Process-Freezer/3000-2094_4-10976629.html). Both works great for me.