# Prevent a process to be suspended

Tags: process

I'm building a program, that have to be always running.

Someone showed me that it can be suspended with Process Explorer like written [here](https://superuser.com/questions/426351/suspend-resume-a-process-the-easy-way).

Is there any way to catch that and resume the process automatically?

Comment: That would depend on whenever that fires a signal or not (which is unlikely) but it's already unlikely that someone would randomly suspend your process. Have a look at [Suspend/resume processes as PsSuspend does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153097/suspend-resume-processes-as-pssuspend-does) as it might get you an idea of how that suspend actually works.

Comment: [Don't try to fight the system administrator.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040216-00/?p=40603/)