# How can I save a program's state and memory and resume it later under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I “hibernate” a program?](https://superuser.com/questions/275010/can-i-hibernate-a-program)

Is there any program/tool for Windows 7(any tool for Windows) that will allow me to save a program's execution state, registers and even memory and save it on the hard drive so that I can resume it later, by later I mean like a day, a week or a month later.

Or is this not possible?

Comment: I agree it's similar, but the suggestions states that I need to use a VM, which I would not. And it was also asked last year, maybe this year and this month there is a way.